# Mobile Safari prompting Windows/NTLM authentication for some media (e.g., MP4)

Tags: ios, html, authentication, video, safari

Right, bear with me on this, I'll try to explain it the best I can.

I have a web application that is running under Windows (Active Directory, NTLM) Authentication.  Within this application, I have a HTML `<video>` element pointing to a .mp4 file on the server.

I access the application, and get prompted (by the browser) to enter credentials.  I do so, and I have access to the application, and the video plays.

Works fine on a desktop (Chrome, etc.), but **when I fire it up in Safari on an iPad (iOS 8+), I get a secondary credentials prompt when the video is loaded (and another prompt for each and every subsequent video rendered).**  If I enter correct credentials here, the video plays, no problem.  If I cancel the prompt, the video doesn't play.  If I navigate away from the page, and go back to the video, I get prompted for credentials again.

Looking at the server logs (IIS 7.5), I see 3 requests for every resource from Safari, the first 2 being returned as 401.2, and the final one returned as 200 (or 206 for .mp4).

What I can't understand is why the .mp4 request prompts for the credentials again, but all other resources work as expected.  I've got a suspicion that other media types cause this behaviour too, but I haven't been able to nail them down yet.

I've read comments here and there that Safari sandboxes its media, and as authentication is not passed through to it, it needs to establish authentication again.  Even though that kinda feels like what's happening, I'd like to have some proper documentation to point to if this is the case.

**Otherwise, does anyone know how to prevent subsequent authentication prompts once the user has already been authenticated, specifically when media (mp4) is rendered?**

Comment: Did you every find a solution for it? I am facing the same issue in Chrome on Android 6.1, whenever i load a mp4 file it asks me for the credentials for 3 times, if i don't pass these, the video plays, but if i pass the (correct) credentials it doesn't play.

Comment: @MuhammadUsmanShahid No, unfortunately not - we've still got it as an outstanding issue.  I'm pretty convinced that it's a bug in Safari, so I'm hoping it will just get fixed one day.  I've not tried it on Android, so I can't say for certain whether it's the same issue (although it does sound suspiciously similar).

Answer (score 0):

Seems like i have found a solution to suppress the authentication popups at least in android. To check if this works for safari too, try to include the below in your web.config file of the target site hosted in IIS. I faced the same issue and I am trying to play mp4 files from a SharePoint (IIS) site in chrome on an android device (v. 6.1).

`<browserCaps>
  <result type="System.Web.Mobile.MobileCapabilities, System.Web.Mobile, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
  <filter>isMobileDevice=false</filter>
</browserCaps>`

You might as well need to disable windows authentication and enable anonymous authentication for it to work. It is only a workaround and cannot be an ideal solution because if I am logged in to the site, I cannot play the video. But if I try to access the site anonymously and play mp4 using HTML5 video tag, it works fine. Probably windows authentication is messing with the video playback on mobile devices.

[See this link as well](http://forums.iis.net/t/1222176.aspx?Windows%20Authentication%20breaks%20video%20playback%20on%20IIS7).